# from where/how is the figure of 50 m sec protection switching time calculated in case of ERP/ MPLS?

Tags: switching, mpls

From where or how does the figure of 50 m sec protection switching calculated for MPLS/ ERPS?

Comment: I use a traffic generator (e.g. IXIA) - transmit 1000PPS, if less than 50 packet drop upon switchover thats your sub-50msec

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The 50 ms maximum delay is a figure derived from practical use. Many real-time protocols can suffer a packet loss for that period without too much impact. That limit is a trade-off between reliability and cost.

It's "offical" in some IETF RFCs, probably starting with [RFC 6378](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6378).

I also found [this source](https://www.slideshare.net/CiscoSP360/putting-50ms-in-perspective) stating that 50 ms originated from Automated Protection Switching (APS).

Comment: Yes, I have gone through the source too but it does not show how this figure is calculated. I am looking for some mathematical derivation behind this figure. There has to be. But I am unable to figure it out.